# Teams Task module custom HTML is not appearing botbuilder sdk framework nodejs

Tags: node.js, botframework, bots, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am using this sample https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/54.teams-task-module to create a teams task module.

I have given a list of valid domain in the manifest file. It is loading the adaptive cards from task module , but not any custom html from /pages directory. Has anyone else faced a similar issue. Adaptive cards from task module is loading but not any custom html page. Does anyone else has a working sample with custom HTML.

Comment: Hi @Atul kumar singh Thanks for reaching out us, will repro at my end and will get back you soon.

Comment: Hi @Atul I have reproduced the same code that you have provided. It is working completely fine at our end and so, I suggest you to retry once again at your end.

Comment: Could you please let us know if your issue has been resolved.

Comment: Hi @Chetana-MSFT yes my issue has been resolved. Probably, you guys should update the document. It say's that if i pass the BOT id from where the task module is invoked while submitting, it will submit. But, i had to pass Teams APP ID , only then it worked. It did not worked with Bot ID.